# Add clicked link's alias to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I've got an Automation populating a Data Extension with all clicks for an email send, but I need to append the alias for each link as well. Is there any way to achieve this? I can't see any way to access the tracking alias using data views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `linkName` in the [**_Click**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) data view.  That's the alias.